# Getting the file name of a file processed in a collection

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have tried to process a lot of xml files using an xslt that is validating some business rules. Whenever I find something that is wrong, I try to log that case in a text file.

I am basically trying something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="3.0"
                expand-text="true">
   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
   <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
   
   <xsl:param name="files" select="uri-collection('file:///C:/Tmp/ProjectA')"/>
   
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:result-document href="out.txt" method="text">
         <!-- All docs starts with root, and I do not want to end up in this initial template more than once, so I aim for "root" in each doc. -->
         <xsl:apply-templates select="$files ! doc(.)/root"/> 
      </xsl:result-document>
   </xsl:template>
   
   <!-- additional templates that checks each BR. Ex: -->
   <xsl:template match="list[not(ancestor-or-self::descr)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="fn:tokenize(document-uri(),'/')[last()]"/> <!-- This is my problem -->
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>Lists not allowed unless in descr.</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>------------------------------------------------</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It seems that the processed document is unavailable when I need to output its name. There are a lot of templates that could be triggered so I need to be able to get it in all templates.

I've also tried a collection, but no luck there either. Is it possible at all? Do I need to create a param and tunnel it to all other templates? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `base-uri()` instead of `document-uri`.

See the Saxon documentation https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!functions/fn/document-uri saying:

> The W3C specification requires that if document-uri(D) = U, then
> doc(U) is D. A consequence of this rule is that two different
> documents cannot have the same document URI. This realisation led to a
> significant change in the implementation of the function beween Saxon
> 10 and 11, with the effect that many documents no longer have a
> document URI. For example, at one time a document built from a JAXP
> Source object would automatically have a document-uri() based on the
> systemID property of the Source. This is no longer the case, because
> there is no way of preventing two different Source objects having the
> same systemID property.

In the end `base-uri()` tends to continue to work where `document-uri()` fails.

Comment: Martin to the rescue, as always - it worked! In my previous uses, in other xslt:s, both document-uri() and base-uri() have yielded the same result, but not here. Could you explain the difference? I do not understand the docs/spec fully.

Comment: I don't think the difference is in the current spec, rather it turned out that Saxon's implementation didn't meet the spec requirement to always return the same document-uri for the same document and therefore changed; I have added a link to the documentation section giving some background information.